# Python: sort a sequence of items into a two-dimensional array of strings, integers, and floating-point numbers using type function

Tags: python, list, loops

The function should loop through the contents of a sequence, and sort the elements by their data type.

The function should return a two-dimensional list (regardless of whether the parameter was a list or tuple). The
list should have three outer elements that represent the three data types being sorted. The basic structure
should look like this:
[ [ list of string elements ], [ list of integer elements ], [ list of float elements ] ]
The returned elements should appear in the same order as they did in the parameter, but with their own data
types

Test Examples:
sort_str_int_float_list([“foo”,3,7.5]) should return [[“foo”],[3],[7.5]]
sort_str_int_float_list([1.0,“foo”,3,”bar”,9,7.5]) should return [[“foo”,”bar”],[3,9],[1.0,7.5]]
sort_str_int_float_list([1.0,“foo”,”3”,”bar”,9,7.5]) should return [[“foo”,”3”,”bar”],[9],[1.0,7.5]]

```
import yourFileHere as testFile

def test_my_function():
    # Initialize score accumulator to 0
    score = 0

    # Sequence of sequences - test arguments and expected results
    TEST_DATA = (
        (['foo',3,7.5],[['foo'],[3],[7.5]]),        
        ([1.0,'foo',3,'bar',9,7.5], [['foo','bar'],[3,9],[1.0,7.5]]),
        ([1.0,'foo','3','bar',9,7.5],[['foo','3','bar'],[9],[1.0,7.5]]),
        (('bar',3,7.5),[['bar'],[3],[7.5]]),
        ((1.0,'foo','bar','7.5'), [['foo','bar','7.5'],[],[1.0]])
        )

    # Loop through test data and test
    for test in TEST_DATA:
        testarg = test[0]
        expected = test[1]

        # Print test data
        print("Test argument:", testarg)
        print("Expected result:", expected)

        # Get result and print
        result = testFile.sort_str_int_float_list(testarg)
        print("Result:",result)

        # If expected result, add 5 to score
        if result == expected:
            score += 5
            print ("Passed.")
        else:
            print ("Failed.")

    # Output final score
    print("Score:",score)


test_my_function()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). See also [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.